# angularjs-ui-grid has extra white space after scrolling to the bottom of the list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When I have enough rows in my ui-grid to do scrolling, it seems to have a lot of whitespace at the bottom of the list for some reason.

I've nailed it down to this piece of code (i think?):

`styles['margin-top'] = hiddenRowWidth + 'px';`

line 3038 of ui-grid.js

Not sure why it's adding so much white space at the bottom though. Any ideas? I was thinking it's because my container is 100% height, but it seems to do this even with a specific pixel height as well.

edit: Well, now I'm not certain that it was that code that's the culprit. The ui-grid-canvas element has a HUGE height, still not sure why.

Closing this out, as it seems to be something CSS related that's only a problem for my custom CSS.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? I have fixed-height grids and no issues with whitespace at the bottom of the list.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what the issue is without any sort of demo to look at.  My guess is that this is a CSS issue rather than an issue with Angular UI Grid.  Any chance you can mock something up to look at?

Comment: Working on setting up a plunkr as we speak.

Comment: You're right, it's gotta be something CSS related. Luckily for me, I put everything under a specific class that I put on all of my ui-grids, so it was easy for me to check by just removing that class. I guess I'll be doing some CSS cleanup today :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the culprit.

I had added `padding: 0` to .ui-grid-canvas, because the 1px space between the header border and the start of the rows was really bugging me. However, for whatever reason this breaks the calculations when it's trying to handle virtualization for scrolling.

Upon removing my custom padding, everything seems to work normally.

Comment: I would never have found this.  Thanks!