# Angular ui-grid empty space on scrolling to bottom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

It looks like angular ui-grid, in some cases, wrongly calculating or canvasHeight or top margin of first row from renderedRows - result is big blank space in the ending, when scrolling to bottom of the list. 
It can be "fixed" in GridRenderContainer.prototype.adjustRows function, by increasing self.grid.options.excessRows number, or calling self.updateViewableRowRange with lesser range start position, but this leads to rendering of hidden rows, that, kinda, killing sense of ui-grid using.

Also, this problem can be "fixed", by adjusting ui-grid canvas element height by jquery.

Is there correct way to fix this problem?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues) could be nice place to ask this

Comment: Try checking this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461624/angularjs-ui-grid-has-extra-white-space-after-scrolling-to-the-bottom-of-the-lis Looks like a similar issue.